# Can't open guard-jasmine.coffee, No response from the Jasmine runner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jasmine, guard, phantomjs

When I try to run [guard-jasmine](https://github.com/netzpirat/guard-jasmine) in my guard set up or in the independent guard-jasmine command I get this error

```
Guard::Jasmine starts thin test server on port 8888 in test environment.
Waiting for Jasmine test runner at http://example.com:8888/
Run Jasmine suite spec/javascripts/credit_card_spec.js
Run Jasmine suite at http://example.com:8888/?spec=CreditCard
Can't open '/home/yuvilio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@agilerails/bundler/gems/guard-jasmine-0fd614d12263/lib/guard/jasmine/phantomjs/guard-jasmine.coffee'
ERROR: No response from the Jasmine runner!
```

Strangely, the 'guard-jasmine.coffee' file is indeed there and seems fine.

My Gemfile includes:

```rb
group :test, :development do
  #...
  gem 'guard-jasmine', :git => "https://github.com/netzpirat/guard-jasmine.git", :branch => 'master'
  gem 'jasminerice', :git => "https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice.git", :branch => 'master'
  gem 'jasmine'
end
```

my Guardfile includes:

```rb
guard 'jasmine', :all_on_start => false, :server => :thin, :port => 8888,  :jasmine_url => 'http://localhost:8888/', :server_env => :test do
  watch(%r{spec/javascripts/spec\.(js\.coffee|js|coffee)$})         { "spec/javascripts" }
  watch(%r{spec/javascripts/.+_spec\.(js\.coffee|js|coffee)$})
  watch(%r{app/assets/javascripts/(.+?)\.(js\.coffee|js|coffee)$})  { |m| "spec/javascripts/#{m[1]}_spec.#{m[2]}" }
end
```

When I run `rake jasmine` and browse to that http://example.com:8888/?spec=CreditCard test, it shows up fine (the test currently fails as expected).  Any idea what is causing the guard

**Postscript:**

This turned out to be a phantomjs issue. @netzpirat correctly diagnosed it in [a comment in his answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086068/cant-open-guard-jasmine-coffee-no-response-from-the-jasmine-runner/11088081#comment14529251_11088081). I was using Ubuntu, whose latest phantomjs was version 1.4. The "Can't open" error was happening there (related to [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=175) perhaps?). To resolve, I found a [PPA that had 1.5](https://launchpad.net/~antono/+archive/phantomjs) and installed it from there (it's also available directly for more architectures [here](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/downloads/list) ). That fixed it.

Comment: Thanks so much, I just ran into this issue. The PPA fixed it for me, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using Jasminerice to serve the Jasmine specs through the asset pipeline, the URL is `http://localhost:8888/jasmine` by default. Since this is also the guard-jasmine default, you can simply skip the option (also port 8888 is default):

```
guard 'jasmine', :all_on_start => false, :server => :thin, :server_env => :test do
  watch(%r{spec/javascripts/spec\.(js\.coffee|js|coffee)$})         { "spec/javascripts" }
  watch(%r{spec/javascripts/.+_spec\.(js\.coffee|js|coffee)$})
  watch(%r{app/assets/javascripts/(.+?)\.(js\.coffee|js|coffee)$})  { |m| "spec/javascripts/#{m[1]}_spec.#{m[2]}" }
end
```

The reason why I have chosen `development` as the default for `:server_env` is, that you'll see the real file name where an error has occurred. I recommend to have it set to `development` for local development and `test` on the CI server.

Comment: Yeah, I was messing with the setups (which server, which env) to see if that made a difference. I switched it back to the default, per your example and still get that `can't open`..`guard-jasmine.coffee` error when I restart everything.

Comment: Can you try to start the debug spec runner with the `guard-jasmine-debug` helper executable? This runs just the CoffeeScript based spec runner within PhantomJS and outputs the raw spec result as JSON.

Comment: Got the same `Can't open` error message as above for that file which is there and looks fine)displayed when running that one.

Comment: OK, so it might be a PhantomJS issue. The script you've used is just [a small two line wrapper](https://github.com/netzpirat/guard-jasmine/blob/master/bin/guard-jasmine-debug). Can you try to execute `phantomjs /home/yuvilio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@agilerails/bundler/gems/guard-jasmine-0fd614d12263/lib/guard/jasmine/phantomjs/guard-jasmine.coffee`?